# Cannot seem to understand Firebase's JSON table

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have this JSON tree:

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

How can I do this in [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase)? Every time I create an object under "employees", with the name "firstname", it replaces the previous object with "Firstname".

I previously used Parse's tables, but since it's been taken down, then I  need help learning this confusing thing.

I'm using Android.

Comment: You can read official documentation at https://www.firebase.com/docs/. Also mention platform for which do you want to use firebase (iOS, Android, web) then it will be easier for others to help you with this.

Comment: @Dzikovskyy I read the documentation, but it isn't really helping.

Comment: And inserting my platform is useless, but I will edit the post.

Comment: did you try `employees.push({firstName:"newFirstName", lastName:"newLastName"})`

Comment: @JoeHanink Where do I write that in? Also just a reminder I am using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase databases have no native support for lists or arrays. If we try to store an list or an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names ([see doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)).

```
// we send this
['hello', 'world']
// Firebase databases store this
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

In this way your tree in firebase would look like this:

```
{"employees":{
        0:{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
        1:{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
        2:{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
    }
}
```

Using Firebase terminology we can say that node emloyees has three child nodes with IDs 0,1,2 respectively.

But saving data with integer IDs in Firebase is not recommended ([see this to know why](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)). Firebase provides a `push()` function that generates a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

Here is an example from Firebase Android doc.:

```
//create firebase ref using your firebase url    
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog");

    Firebase postRef = ref.child("posts");

    Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post1.put("author", "gracehop");
    post1.put("title", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language");
    postRef.push().setValue(post1);

    Map<String, String> post2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post2.put("author", "alanisawesome");
    post2.put("title", "The Turing Machine");
    postRef.push().setValue(post2);
```

And as a result in posts node we will have two childs with autogenerated ids:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "author": "alanisawesome",
      "title": "The Turing Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `DatabaseReference.push()`, which creates a new child under the location.

```
var employeesRef = mDatabase.child("employees");
var newEmployeeRef = employeesRef.push()
newEmployeeRef.setValue(employee);
```

The best place to read more about this is in the section on [appending data to a list in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Comment: I am using Java. But I got the idea. I'll see if it works